# UpdatePanel with GridView and Progressbar not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, progress-bar, updatepanel

I need help. I have a progress bar that triggered after clicking a button. This button runs stored procedure in SQL that will update tables that i later bind for the gridview, after running the stored procedure i execute code to update the gridview. The problem is, after the progress bar came out, i expected that the gridview will automatically refresh/update but it did not happened. Please help.

ASPX - GridView:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel9" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridExportExcel" runat="server" >
...........Blah
                    </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExecSP" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

ProgressBar:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DynamicLayout="false">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="loading" runat="server" ImageUrl="loading.gif" />
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Code Behind from button: - This Stored Procedure runs about 3 mins.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            GridExportExcel.DataSource = dt;
            GridExportExcel.DataBind();

            //UpdatePanel9.Update();

            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            string selectSQL = "exec dbo.StoredPRoc'" + txtcomp.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "'";


            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            DT = ExecGetData(selectSQL);

            header(); //Update the Gridview.
```

Thank You -
Renz

---

Hi Brian thanks for the reply. I am not allowed to create indexes in the table. I did some work around and removed the progress bar and it works fine, though the query/storedproc still execute in 3 mins. the gridview are now updating.  How can i show the progress bar without timing out? Is there any way to do this? I appreciate your reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your code, please...

Comment: Hi Wizzardz Please see code above. Thanks.

Comment: @wizzardz any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that you are timing out, and therefore the new result doesn't come back.  To verify this, try binding to a test query that only takes a few seconds to run, and see if the results come back from that.  If that is true, then it would be the query.

Are there any efficiencies you can make to the query, like applying indexes, or use an alternative querying approach?  3 minutes is a very long time to run for a web application.

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for the reply. I am not allowed to create indexes in the table. I did some work around and removed the progress bar and it works fine, though the query/storedproc still execute in 3 mins. the gridview are now updating.  How can i show the progress bar without timing out? Is there any way to do this? I appreciate your reply. Thanks in advance.